# Sustainable diapers?

Tags: alternatives, hygiene, baby

I'm looking for a sustainable overnight (read: long lasting, high-absorbancy) diaper for my 3yo daughter. She has been cloth diapered since she was a newborn, but now I just can't find an overnight cloth diaper that won't leak and I can't just change her bedsheets every day until she can use the toilet on her own. That, itself, is not sustainable for the environment or my energy!

I would like to find a disposable diaper that won't outlive my grandchildren in a landfill. Something at least a little friendlier to the environment than your more mainstream (insert popular brand here).

Can anyone help me find a sustainable alternative for the next year or so?

Comment: have you tried double-diapering? That was the usual overnight approach.

Comment: What do you mean by double-diapering? I added an extra hemp insert for absorbency, if that's what you mean. Still didn't stop the leaks...

Comment: We used separate diapers and covers. At night, we put two diapers in the cover. But by age three it's a challenge, to be sure.

Comment: I don't want to sound like I'm being mean, but the most sustainable thing for both the environment and your personal time would be to potty train your daughter. Again, I'm not trying to brag, but my wife and I are currently potty training our 16 month old. Its hard since she's so young, but we're making progress. You can do it.

Comment: Trust me when I tell you she's simply not ready. Congratulations on your potty training prodigy, but I know my daughter and I know she's not there yet. This has been a process since she was about 18mo and I'm not going to bore the internet with the story. We're doing what's best for her.

Comment: There are several diapers in production that (claim to) use renewable ressources and degrade biologically, in Germany you'd google "Öko-Windeln" - but not knowing where you live, I can't know if any are availabe.

Comment: We used doubled-up cloth nappies with a wool outer (Google "wool soakers") which helps with leakage, but have eventually given up and use Naty disposables at night.  They seem to have pretty wide distribution.

Comment: I remember we used eco-friendly diapers for a short while from a brand called [Naty](https://www.naty.com). They are FSC and biobased certified, so it may be slightly better than the more common brands. However it's been several years since we used them and I vaguely remember switching to a different brand  back then. Not sure why that was, probably because we weren't satisfied with them.

Comment: Can't you just put some incontinence pads under her?

Comment: Also interested in what your current cloth diapers are... Maybe switching brand/approach with cloth would work as well

Answer (score 1):

Look for the adult stuff... I [read here](https://www.treehugger.com/clean-technology/adult-diapers-clog-landfills-too.html) they advise

> to use a **booster pad** or "diaper doubler".

Maybe this is a solution for your case?

Also they are talking about

> **"long-lasting" diaper** typically found in Europe

(btw Are you in the States?

Comment: In the US I would search for 'washable incontinence pads'.